# Where are records of fund ownership held between platform and fund

Tags: united-kingdom

I own a number of units in a fund. Does the fund know that I own those units? Or only the platform on which I hold them?

To put it another way:

If different customers own units in the same fund on the same platform, does the fund itself know that customer A owns 25 units and customer B owns 10. Or does the fund just know that the platform's customers hold 35 between them and only the platform knows how they're distributed between customers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fund just knows that the platform’s customers hold 35 between them, and only the platform knows who owns those units.

One of the benefits for funds of using platforms is that it simplifies the distribution a great deal, they just have a chunk of money to deal with while all the bits and bobs of payments and anti-money laundering and communications with the individual investors etc. is all the job of the platform.